# How to Enable the disabled Next button in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

In My custom page, I have disabled the next button while the page loading... Because there is some background process need to complete, until we cant go to the next page. So I have disable the next button using following code.

```
GetDlgItem $1 $HWNDPARENT 1 
EnableWindow $1 0
```

But I want to enable the next button once background process completed. I have used the follwoing code to enable

```
GetDlgItem $1 $HWNDPARENT 1 
EnableWindow $1 1
```

But it was not worked... cld u please suggest the mistake done by me or how achieve this in NSIS?

Following is My Code

```
Function StartProgressPage
    ; Set dialog text:
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "$(STARTPRGDIA_TITLE)" "$(STARTPRGDIA_SUBTITLE)"

    ; Display the page:
    !insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY "StartPrgDia"

    ;Disable Next Button
    GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1
    EnableWindow $0 0

    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $dialog
    nsDialogs::CreateControl "msctls_progress32" \
        ${DEFAULT_STYLES}|${PBS_SMOOTH} \
        ${PB_EXSTYLE} \
        0 30 100% 10% \
        "Test" \

    Pop $hwnd
    ${NSD_CreateTimer} NSD_Timer.CallStop 10
    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function NSD_Timer.CallStop
    ${NSD_KillTimer} NSD_Timer.CallStop ; Kill the timer
    SendMessage $hwnd ${PBM_SETRANGE32} 0 100

    SendMessage $hwnd ${PBM_SETPOS} 25 0
    Call <Some Process>
    SendMessage $hwnd ${PBM_SETPOS} 50 0
    Call ConfPropertyChanges
    SendMessage $hwnd ${PBM_SETPOS} 100 0
    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 10 20% 10u Completed

    ;Enable Next Button
    GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1
    EnableWindow $0 1
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: It should work. It does for me. How are you launching that background process? I use `ThreadTimer::Start`.

Comment: I have edited my question with my code.. Please look into that and cld u please update me the correct way...

Comment: Your function NSD_Timer.CallStop is never called. Is setting progress bar position working for you fine? Maybe the problem is EnableWindow is called from different thread than main GUI thread.

Comment: Oh Sorry Wrongly copied the code.. I have Edited the code above.. just look into that... And also the progress bar working.. But it is not moving step by step.. Its wait for all the process completes and reached 100% in a sec...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know installer will wait inside this code:

```
!insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY "StartPrgDia"
```

until user goes to the next page.
Are you sure that the code bellow this line is executed when custom page is displayed?

You should call

```
!insertmacro MUI_INSTALLOPTIONS_DISPLAY "StartPrgDia"
```

after all your code or use this(MUI2 version)

```
Function CustomPage
    !insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_INITDIALOG "page.ini"

    # your code here

    !insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_SHOW

FunctionEnd
```